# How to view logs in Firebase cloudfunctions

Tags: node.js, firebase, google-cloud-functions

I'm writing my very first cloudfunctions app:

```
import * as functions from "firebase-functions";
import admin = require("firebase-admin")

admin.initializeApp();

export const random_questions = functions.https.onRequest(async (req, res) => {
  const allQuestions = (await admin.database().ref('questions').get()).toJSON();
  functions.logger.log('params', req.params);
  res.send(allQuestions);
});
```

As you can see I put a log in my app, but is not shown in my terminal or in the ui emulator suite (localhost:4000) or using `firebase functions:log`.

Edit:
UI suite screenshot:
[image: random_question is the function I'm testing]

What am I missing?

Comment: Can you send a screenshot of emulator suite logs?

Answer (score 1):

I found the issue:

I was testing using:

```
 firebase emulators:start --only functions
```

that always run the same code. To run your code after a change use

```
"npm run build && firebase emulators:start --only functions",
```

or simply

```
"npm run serve"
```